# How to fix pattern, that I use to get list of files in folder with standard library glob?

Tags: python, directory, glob

I have the following files:

```
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.71.gz
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.63.gz
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.11
/tmp/test_glob/core_dump.log
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.32
/tmp/test_glob/dm.log
/tmp/test_glob/client.log
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.1
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.64.gz
```

I want to get all .log files, EXCEPT the files, that end with .gz.
The desired result should be the following:

```
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.11
/tmp/test_glob/core_dump.log
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.32
/tmp/test_glob/dm.log
/tmp/test_glob/client.log
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.1
```

I have written this simple code:

```
import glob
import os

glob_pattern = u'*.log*'
for log_path in glob.glob(os.path.join('/tmp/test_glob', glob_pattern)):
    print('log_path: ', log_path)
```

but it returns all file from folder /tmp/test_glob/

I tried to modify this pattern like this:

```
glob_pattern = u'*.log.[0-9][0-9]'
```

but it returns only

```
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.11
/tmp/test_glob/client.log.32
```

How to fix this pattern ?

Answer (score 1):

Using Pythex(a Python regex tester), the match string

```
glob_pattern = u'.*(\.log)(?!.*(gz)).*'
```

Worked well for your goal.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. This pattern returns no files.

Comment: This is a `re`. It is not a glob pattern; attempting to use it with glob will not work. But it is a solution if one uses the `re` module to do the filtering rather than using the glob translator.

Answer (score 0):

Try `**/*.log!(*.gz)`

[Test using globster.xyz](https://globster.xyz/?q=**%2F*.log!(*.gz)&f=%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log.71.gz%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log.63.gz%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log.11%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fcore_dump.log%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log.32%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fdm.log%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log.1%2C%2Ftmp%2Ftest_glob%2Fclient.log.64.gz)

Comment: This is a bash extglob, not something that the Python glob module supports

Answer (score 0):

That isn't a glob pattern. You don't want `glob`. You want to use the `re` module functions to filter the results of `os.listdir`.